# Is it possible to set the changeHash in pagecontainer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to set some parameters in a URL with `Pagecontainer Widget`?

This is what I got:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#home', {
            changeHash: true,
            transition: 'fade',
            reverse: true
        });
```

The browsers URL look like this then:
**www.myurl.com/index.html#home**

I need it like this:
**www.myurl.com/index.html?id=apple#home**

It this somehow possible?